# ASP.NET Core Secure Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core project that has a Web API for mobile device (Xamarin).
I want to secure the api with ASP.NET Core identity, but the problem is when I authenticate a device and authenticated successfully, in another request it not still authenticated:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] LogIn l)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(l.username);

    if(user == null)
    {
        user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(l.username);
    }

    if(user != null)
    {
        await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, l.password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await signInManager.RememberTwoFactorClientAsync(user);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
    }

    return Ok(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

The code that needs to authorize to return data :

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var b = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(o => o.BookId == id);
    return Ok(b);
}
```

I read about token and jwt but I don't know how to use them. Any Idea how to secure the API and make the device authenticated once they log in?

Comment: Here's a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's late, but I think the idea is to `login` the user, and return a `token` that's then saved to the client's(Xamarin Android/iOS for your case) `local storage/Sharedpreferences`. The saved token can then be used for `subsequent` Web API calls for authentication without the need to login. It can then be cleared when a user logs out. For **JWT**, you can restructure your login function as follows:

```
var token = await GetJwtSecurityToken(user);
 return Ok(new
        {
         token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
        });
```

The **GetJwtSecurityToken()** can look like this depending on your needs:

```
 private async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GetJwtSecurityToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            return new JwtSecurityToken(
                //issuer: "http://localhost:****/",                
                //audience: "http://localhost:****/",
                audience: "http://localhost:****/",
                claims: GetTokenClaims(user).Union(userClaims),//Combine user & claims
                //expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("x%u<-Q.@w^:qF]2Hz4")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
        }
```

The `GetTokenClaims()` function can look like:

```
private static IEnumerable<Claim> GetTokenClaims(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return new List<Claim>
        {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
        new Claim("Email", user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
        new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName)
        //Other user info
        };
    }
```

You can then save this token in local storage/Sharedpreferences, and use it to authenticate your API calls. You can research on: How to decode **JWT token** in Xamarin, OpenId..

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it and tell you how it goes.

Comment: Okay, you'll mark it as answer if it helps. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: Hello, Felix, I did what you write but know how to use the token to request the API and how the method should handle it, Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you, am waiting for you,